# i am unable to type text in loginpage by using sendkeys

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am unable to type text in login page, tried all the solutions provided online but issue still exists. anyone help me to resolve the issue. below is the code:

```
package com.individual.newlearn;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class secondProgram {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "./driver/chromedriver.exe");
    ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("https://www.google.co.in/webhp?ie=UTF-8&rct=j&gws_rd=cr&dcr=0&ei=9Wq2WozGFIH4vgSJ2LmoAw");
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text()='Gmail']")).click();
    //driver.navigate().to("https://accounts.google.com/signin/v2/identifier?hl=EN&flowName=GlifWebSignIn&flowEntry=ServiceLogin");


    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text()='Sign In']")).click();
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    driver.findElement(By.id("identifierId")).sendKeys("mail id");
```

java script i used for typing mail id:

```
/*WebElement searchbox = driver.findElement(By.id("identifierId"));
    JavascriptExecutor myExecutor = ((JavascriptExecutor)driver);
    myExecutor.executeScript("arguments[0].value='mail id';", searchbox);
    Thread.sleep(3000);*/
```

Comment: I tried with chrome driver version 2.37 and chrome version 65.0 using C# binding and they are working as expected . I was able to follow along gmail > signin > set email id  steps . Try performing a click before trying to sendKeys or increase the wait before send keys.. Also, consider using explicit waits on webdriver instead of Thread.sleep..

Comment: Thank you Nish26... i will try as u suggested....